# Unable to have get and set method in Object Constructor (not in class) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, getter-setter

When creating simple Object literal we can easily have get/set method.

```
const John = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  teach: "Physics",
  language: "en",
  get lang() {
    return this.teach;
  }
};

John.teach //isValid
```

But what if we want to define get/set in Object Constructor. (Not Class one).
I tried this way but it's not working...

```
    function Faculties (fName,lName,teach,lang){
      this.firstName = fName;
      this.lastName = lName;
      this.teach = teach;
      this.language = lang;
      get this.lang() = function(){
        return this.teach
    }
  }
```

any help would be appreciated..thank uh

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: You can define a getter in the prototype:
`Object.defineProperty(Faculties.prototype, 'lang', {get: function() { return this.teach }});`

Comment: @CristianTraîna thank uh...So that's the only way we can have get/set other then Object literal?

Comment: Yes, but consider that this way of creating objects is kinda legacy